# Constructing an sql Query to get records betwen two dates

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to filter out and report records in a database that fall between a specified date range. I'm there are other threads here on how to do something similar, but my dates are stored as date timestamps (which is why I think the issue is arising)

My current query is as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM JOURNAL WHERE Date_Time>'10/10/2013 00:00:00'"
```

(Note that journal is the name of the table I'm pulling the data from and date_time is the field in which the date is stored. I'm aware the query doesn't quite do what I want it to yet, but I was just testing out a simpler case at first.)

When I run this query (as part of an excel macro), excel reports that it can't find any records even though I know their are records past this date. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Edit: I've got it, it was an issue unrelated to the query (something else in the macro) Thanks so much for the help (changing the date format worked)

Comment: Can you verify that field Date_Time is in fact a date data type and not a string?

Comment: I've asked excel what type of field it is and it reports that its a date timestamp. Also, my query is sort of working now (see edit) so I have confidence it isn't a string

Comment: Can you check the actual database instead? Also, what RDBMS is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried other date format? like this:
     "SELECT * FROM JOURNAL WHERE Date_Time>'2013-10-10:00:00:00'"

Comment: I tried this, and actually made progress. Excel now just returns the records that happen on that day though, but not any day after that (so it'll get records for 10/10/2013, but not 10/11/2013 or any day afterward

Comment: Somewhere else in the code I had set it to only pull 1 day for testing purposes and had totally forgotten about I did that. After making that change, this query worked perfectly, so yes

Answer (score 0):

A simple between statement is what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM JOURNAL WHERE Date_Time between '10/10/2013 00:00:00' and '[otherdate]'
```

You need to run this to check for one important thing:  If the server is running the BETWEEN as inclusive or not.  If it's inclusive, both dates are included.  If not, the range will begin either before or after one or both.

I've seen SQL servers that are the same in every respect actually treat this condition differently.    So it's a good idea to check that.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing special about the timestamp? I tried running your query(which is a similar one to what I've posted above) and excel still returns no records.

Comment: What if you remove the `WHERE` clause, do you get all the records?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had before, but importing such a large dataset into excel is painfully slow

Comment: You could also try changing the format of your date format to '2013-10-10 00:00:00'.  SQL my be chocking on it because it is resolving to a totally unknown date.

Comment: I tried this out and it worked sort of. It now returns any record that happened that day, but no records on the next day or any day after that. I'm assuming its because its doing its comparison using the time portion of the date. Not sure how to change that though.

Comment: It's not though.  The time is PART of the date.  It's all one big object.  So, '1/1/2014 00:30:00' is greater than '1/1/2014 00:20:00'.  At least as far as SQL sees it.